# Sql Left or Right Join One To Many Pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one main table and join other tables via left outer or right outer outer join.One row of main table have over 30 row in join query as result. And I try pagination. But the problem is I can not know how many rows will it return for one main table row result.

Example :

Main table first row result is in my query 40 rows.
Main table second row result is 120 row.

**Problem(Question) UPDATE:**
For pagination I need give the pagesize the count of select result. But I can not know the right count for my select result. Example I give page no 1 and pagesize 50, because of this I cant get the right result.I need give the right pagesize for my main table top 10 result. Maybe for top 10 row will the result row count 200 but my page size is 50 this is the problem.

I am using Sql 2014. I need it for my ASP.NET project but is not important.

**Sample UPDATE :**

it is like searching an hotel for booking. Your main table is hotel table. And the another things are (mediatable)images, (mediatable)videos, (placetable)location and maybe (commenttable)comments they are more than one rows and have one to many relationship for the hotel. For one hotel the result will like 100, 50 or 10 rows for this all info. And I am trying to paginate this hotels result. I need get always 20 or 30 or 50 hotels for performance in my project.

**Sample Query  UPDATE :**

```
   SELECT  
      *
   FROM
      KisiselCoach KC
         JOIN WorkPlace WP
            ON KC.KisiselCoachId = WP.WorkPlaceOwnerId
         JOIN Album A
            ON KC.KisiselCoachId = A.AlbumId
            JOIN Media M
               ON A.AlbumId = M.AlbumId
         LEFT JOIN Rating R
            ON KC.KisiselCoachId = R.OylananId 
         JOIN FrUser Fr
            ON KC.CoachId = Fr.UserId 
         JOIN UserJob UJ
            ON KC.KisiselCoachId = UJ.UserJobOwnerId 
            JOIN Job J
               ON UJ.JobId = J.JobId 
         JOIN UserExpertise UserEx
            ON KC.KisiselCoachId = UserEx.UserExpertiseOwnerId
            JOIN Expertise Ex
               ON UserEx.ExpertiseId = Ex.ExpertiseId




Hotel Table : 
HotelId   HotelName
1         Barcelona
2         Berlin


Media Table :
MediaID   MediaUrl      HotelId
1         www.xxx.com   1
2         www.xxx.com   1
3         www.xxx.com   1
4         www.xxx.com   1


Location Table :
LocationId   Adress          HotelId 
1            xyz, Berlin     1
2            xyz, Nice       1
3            xyz, Sevilla    1
4            xyz, Barcelona  1


Comment Table :
CommentId   Comment             HotelId
1           you are cool        1
2           you are great       1
3           you are bad         1
4           hmm you are okey    1
```

This is only sample! I have 9999999 hotels in my database. Imagine a hotel maybe it has 100 images maybe zero. I can not know this. And I need get 20 hotels in my result(pagination). But 20 hotels means 1000 rows maybe or 100 rows.

Comment: What is the problem? What's the actual question?

Comment: For pagination I need give the pagesize the count of select result. But I can not know the right count for my select result. example I give page no 1 and pagesize 50 because of this I cant get the right result.I need give the right pagesize for my main table top 10 result maybe for 10 row will the result row count 200 but my page size is 50 this is the problem.

Comment: Please provide sample data to illustrate the problem...

Comment: @DaleBurrell I add sample.

Comment: Thats your query, which is very useful, but we need to see some sample *data* to understand the number of rows you are receiving (because we don't have access to your table data).

Comment: @DaleBurrell I have add an example you will understand me. Thanks for your understanding I didn't understand you in your previous post.

Comment: Please google "data", "sample data" and "expected results" in that case.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @DaleBurrell I have add my tables :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your query is poorly written for readability flow / relationship of tables.  I have updated and indented to try and show how/where tables related in hierarchical relativity.

You also want to paginate, lets get back to that.  Are you intending to show every record as a possible item, or did you intend to show a "parent" level set of data... Ex so you have only one instance per Media, Per User, or whatever, then once that entry is selected you would show details for that one entity?  if so, I would do a query of DISTINCT at the top-level, or at least grab the few columns with a count(*) of child records it has to show at the next level.

Also, mixing inner, left and right joins can be confusing.  Typically a right-join means you want the records from the right-table of the join.  Could this be rewritten to have all required tables to the left, and non-required being left-join TO the secondary table?

Clarification of all these relationships would definitely help along with the context you are trying to get out of the pagination.  I'll check for comments, but if lengthy, I would edit your original post question with additional details vs a long comment.

Here is my SOMEWHAT clarified query rewritten to what I THINK the relationships are within your database.  Notice my indentations showing where table A -> B -> C -> D for readability.  All of these are (INNER) JOINs indicating they all must have a match between all respective tables.  If some things are NOT always there, they would be changed to LEFT JOINs

```
SELECT  
      *
   FROM
      KisiselCoach KC
         JOIN WorkPlace WP
            ON KC.KisiselCoachId = WP.WorkPlaceOwnerId
         JOIN Album A
            ON KC.KisiselCoachId = A.AlbumId
            JOIN Media M
               ON A.AlbumId = M.AlbumId
         LEFT JOIN Rating R
            ON KC.KisiselCoachId = R.OylananId 
         JOIN FrUser Fr
            ON KC.CoachId = Fr.UserId 
         JOIN UserJob UJ
            ON KC.KisiselCoachId = UJ.UserJobOwnerId 
            JOIN Job J
               ON UJ.JobId = J.JobId 
         JOIN UserExpertise UserEx
            ON KC.KisiselCoachId = UserEx.UserExpertiseOwnerId
            JOIN Expertise Ex
               ON UserEx.ExpertiseId = Ex.ExpertiseId
```

Readability of a query is a BIG help for yourself, and/or anyone assisting or following you.  By not having the "on" clauses near the corresponding joins can be very confusing to follow.

Also, which is your PRIMARY table where the rest are lookup reference tables.

ADDITION PER COMMENT

Ok, so I updated a query which appears to have no context to the sample data and what you want in your post.  That said, I would start with a list of hotels only and a count(*) of things per hotel so you can give SOME indication of how much stuff you have in detail.  Something like

```
select
      H.HotelID,
      H.HotelName,
      coalesce( MedSum.recs, 0 ) as MediaItems,
      coalesce( LocSum.recs, 0 ) as NumberOfLocations,
      coalesce( ComSum.recs, 0 ) as NumberOfLocations
   from
      Hotel H
         LEFT JOIN
         ( select M.HotelID, 
                  count(*) recs
              from Media M
              group by M.HotelID ) MedSum
            on H.HotelID = MedSum.HotelID
         LEFT JOIN
         ( select L.HotelID, 
                  count(*) recs
              from Location L
              group by L.HotelID ) LocSum
            on H.HotelID = LocSum.HotelID
         LEFT JOIN
         ( select C.HotelID, 
                  count(*) recs
              from Comment C
              group by C.HotelID ) ComSum
            on H.HotelID = ComSum.HotelID
   order by
      H.HotelName
   --- apply any limit per pagination
```

Now this will return every hotel at a top-level and the total count of things per the hotel per the individual counts which may or not exist hence each sub-check is a LEFT-JOIN.  Expose a page of 20 different hotels.  Now, as soon as one person picks a single hotel, you can then drill-into the locations, media and comments per that one hotel.

Now, although this COULD work, having to do these counts on an every-time query might get very time consuming.  You might want to add counter columns to your main hotel table representing such counts as being performed here.  Then, via some nightly process, you could re-update the counts ONCE to get them primed across all history, then update counts only for those hotels that have new activity since entered the date prior.  Not like you are going to have 1,000,000 posts of new images, new locations, new comments in a day, but of 22,000, then those are the only hotel records you would re-update counts for.  Each incremental cycle would be short based on only the newest entries added.  For the web, having some pre-aggregate counts, sums, etc is a big time saver where practical.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions and efforts. I have add my tables could you please look. you will understand me. I will update now my query thank you again :)

Comment: @AlicanKablan, see additional detail at bottom of my previous answer.

Comment: idea is great I will show the comments and locations if they click my hotel. But I need show images like booking or ebay. Do you have idea for this. How are they doing this big companies @drapp